# Star Wars: Where Science Meets Imagination -- How much time to allow?

Tags: planning, children, museums, events, orlando

My 7-year old is a HUGE Star Wars fan.  (As am I, but this is more about him)  I'm planning on taking him to the [Star Wars:  Where Science Meets Imagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_Where_Science_Meets_Imagination) exhibit at the Orlando Science Center.  It's a surprise trip.  Fly down, hit the museum and maybe a theme park, and then come back the next day.

My question is, how much time should I allow for him to see the exhibit?  He's a typical 7 year old, so he's got a 7-year old's attention span.  But, he also loves Star Wars, so I'm sure he's going to gawk over every single item in the exhibit.  Is 2-3 hours enough?  Should I plan for more?

The tickets are timed entry, which is why I ask.  I want to make sure our flight gets in early enough for him to see everything before the museum closes.

Comment: This might be more of a parenting question as it really depends on what kind of kid he is. I'd imagine that someone that young might start by gawking over the exhibits for a while, but after an hour or so he's going to be tired and moving between exhibits far more quickly.

Comment: I voted to close as off-topic (belongs on Parenting) but it also is subjective. Impossible to give a universal answer.

Comment: This might be a better fit on Meta... or Chat.

Comment: Darn! you guys closed it just as I was writing an answer... Other than in the comments, is there a way to post it? I just want to be helpful to the poster, even if it is off topic...

Comment: Anyways, out of 37 exhibits, the average length of stay is about an hour, with adult only groups visiting an average of 21 exhibits compared to 18 for groups with kids under 18 years old. If you intend on visiting every exhibit, 2 hours seems like a reasonable amount of time. For more information, have fun poking at the final report on the exhibit from the Boston MOS here : http://www.exhibitfiles.org/dfile2/ReviewFinding/247/original/Star__Wars__Summative__EvalutionReport__Final.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [final report](http://www.exhibitfiles.org/dfile2/ReviewFinding/247/original/Star__Wars__Summative__EvalutionReport__Final.pdf) from the Museum of Science in Boston, MA, concerning the same exhibit, the average length of stay (of the polled visitors, of course) seems to be around an hour, with the shortest being 15 minutes and the longest being 170 minutes.

The exhibit had 37 stalls/panels in Boston, with the average group visiting a little over 19 of them. For groups composed exclusively of adults, 21 stalls were visited. In comparison, groups that included kids under 18 visited an average of only 18 stalls.

If you intend on visiting every stall/panel in the exhibit, I would believe that 2 hours would be suffient. However, it is probably possible to plan your activity using the chart that is located on pages 43 and 44 of the report. It includes the name of each panel, the percentage of visitors that went to see each and the median amount of time spent there. This way, you can prioritize the stalls/panels that your son would enjoy most in case he becomes tired after a long day walking.

That being said, the exhibit sounds awesome! I wish it stopped somewhere I could go...

Have fun with your son!